# Haskell pure functions and files

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I've read this article on Haskell's approach to IO: https://wiki.haskell.org/IO_inside

I understand how getChar works, but I don't know how to make the following function pure

getFile :: String -> File

where String is filename and File is some defined type which can be used to futher operate on a file.

To my mind this function cannot be correct as it breaks the rule:
"if a function's result changes, it should be because it's arguments have changed." (quote from the article above)

A file can change on the disk and File type can therefore be different for example it can hold a different permission set.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: You can't make it pure, why do you think it would be possible?

Comment: Then how can such a function possibly exist in Haskell?

Comment: Also what is `File`? If that doesn't actually represent an open file handle, but just a location descriptor, then of course it would be possible to construct that as a pure data structure.

Comment: Well `getFile` *doesn't* exist in Haskell. If you're thinking of [`readFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:readFile), that has type `String -> IO File`

Comment: The objective is to minimise the amount of code which is impure. So most of the code is pure, and only a small part is impure, has the 'IO taint'. If much of your code turns out to be impure then this suggests a refactoring would be appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct, you can't make a `getFile` that has the behaviour you want, and the type `String -> File`, and is pure. The simple answer to your question is that because that can't be done, Haskell doesn't do that.

But Haskell doesn't **need** to do that. We **do** of course need a way of identifying a file on disk by name and opening it (and we'll assume we can represent an open file by your `File` type). That's a real need that Haskell needs to support. But there's simply no reason it has to have the specific type `String -> File`; since that's impossible we should make something else with a different type, that can still fulfil this programming need.

You say you understand how `getChar` works, but the answer to how Haskell provides something to address the need of your `getFile` is exactly the same as how it provides something to address the need of `getChar`.

In an imperative language, `getChar` would be a thing that takes no parameters and gives you a `Char`, imperatively. In Haskell a "thing that takes no parameters and gives you a `Char`" translates to just the type `Char`. But `getChar` obviously can't be `Char`, since that implies it is one **particular** `Char`. Instead we give it the type `IO Char`. Things of type `IO a` are **actions** that will produce an `a`, not the `a` itself. So `getChar :: IO Char` is an **action** that will produce a `Char`. It doesn't have to be one single `Char` for all time, rather it is one single **action**, but each time we run the action we get the next `Char` from the input stream.

Similarly, `getFile` in Haskell should have type `String -> IO File`. It is a "factory for file-opening actions"; once we've given it the name of the file the resulting action knows what name it should look up, but only when the action is actually run will it go look at the disk and see whether there is a file there. `getFile` doesn't have to always return the same "open file" for each input `String`, it has to return the same procedure for opening a file of that name. The procedure is always the same, it's just what happens when you try to carry it out that is affected by the disk state.

Haskell the language doesn't provide any way of actually running these `IO` actions. Haskell code is pure, and purely builds up `IO` actions without depending on the external world. The runtime system of Haskell can execute them, and it does so to the `main :: IO a` action (and also if you enter them at the GHCi prompt). But how that happens is not part of the Haskell language, any more than Java defines exactly how system calls work.

That's all there is to it. Things that would be side-effecting `Input1 -> Input2 -> Output` in imperative languages can't have that type in Haskell, so we use different type to represent them; they end up as `Input1 -> Input2 -> IO Output`<sup>1</sup>.

Note I haven't mentioned monads; `IO` *is* a monad, and that provides a lot of handy tools for working with `IO` computations, but it's `IO` itself that lets us work with external side effects because of the special handling in the Haskell runtime, not the fact that it's a monad.

---

Just for completeness: I noticed that article is using the "world-passing" explanation for `IO`, which is actually equivalent to the "`IO` = opaque action" story I used above, but uses a different metaphor.<sup>2</sup>

But if you understood the story as explained in that article, you would know that a way to make a pure function that can do the job of an impure function is to add an extra argument and an extra return value. The article calls the type of this value `Val` or `RealWorld`, but the point is it's abstract. You only ever get one by calling an `IO` action, which required you to pass in a previous world. The runtime system supplies the first one to `main`, so you can thread it through all your calls. In-memory it is an empty value, but it can be said to *represent* the state of the entire universe: the state of every disk, all the network packets in flight, all the humans poised to strike a key or move a mouse, etc; **everything**.

So `getChar`'s impure `Char` type becomes `World -> (Char, World)`; you give it the state of the universe just before you read a character from the input stream, and it gives you back the next character and also the state the world will have just before your next IO action. Inside the Haskell language there is no explanation of how it "computes" what the next universe should be, we just have to assume that it can (just like with the action metaphore we have no explanation for how actions are carried out, we just must assume that the runtime will be able to execute them). Outside the language of course we don't have to do anything to "compute" the universe, because we can just use the passage of time in the real universe to always have a universe available that is consistent with the sequence of universes the program requires.

Similarly, to represent the impure `getFile :: String -> File` we simply add an extra argument and return value, making it `getFile :: String -> World -> (File, World)`. Exactly the same way we handled `getChar`.

One big gotcha I haven't mentioned is that even though the `RealWorld` is abstract so we can't peek inside it or make one up, once the runtime gives us one we could in principle store it and reuse it. That's not how the *real* universe works, so we have to prevent that. Haskell does so by not actually exposing the extra world arguments to normal code; instead we have the `IO` type to represent "taking and returning a world on the side". `IO` is abstract, so you can't look inside it to get access to the `World`. Instead the builtin libraries expose functions for sequencing and combining things of type `IO a` for you, and *those* functions are very careful to make it impossible to accidentally use a `World` value twice. (There are other languages that have the type system features to ensure that a `World` value must be used **exactly** once, and therefore use this "world-passing" system for IO in a way that *does* expose the `World` values to user code)

It's still not very relevant on this picture that `IO` is a monad. That's a very convenient way to provide those builtin functions for combining and sequencing `IO` values, but it could just as well be done without using the concept of a monad at all.

---

<sup>1</sup> This process isn't really so different from the kind of modelling OO programmers do all the time without batting an eyelid. For example, a filesystem is not an instance of a class; it isn't a thing that exists in memory and has methods. But that doesn't stop OO programmers making a class to *represent* a filesystem, such that you can call methods on instances of that class which will be translated into lower level operations on the filesystem.

<sup>2</sup> The actual details of the real implementation in GHC is messy and complicated; it's not exactly either of these two explanations, but also irrelevant to actually programming in Haskell.

Comment: Okay no more concerns, thank you

Comment: It turned out that, although I understood how IO works under the hood, I missed the practical abstraction part